# СМС автоответчик

Tags: android

Неделю бьюсь над кодом, но ничего не выходит. Задача проста - программа при любом входящем смс отправляет на него текст "Я пока что занят и не могу ответить"

Код есть, но он не работает

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){ //пробегаемся по всем полученным сообщениям
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            numbers.add(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress()); //получаем номер отправителя
            messages.add(msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());//получаем текст сообщения
        }
        if (messages.size() > 0){
            //делаем что-то с сообщениями
        }
    } 
}
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.persik.smsparser"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.persik.smsparser.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>        </activity>
    <receiver android:name="MessageReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
  </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: а в чём вопрос? конкретно, где проблема?

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос. Он не хочет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не вижу чтобы ты отправлял смс. зато я отправляю:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> partsOfText = sms.divideMessage(message);
        int count = partsOfText.size();

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    new Intent(SENT), 0));
            deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                    DELIVERED), 0));
        }
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, partsOfText,
                sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

    }
```